# Trouble running Elastic agent in a Kubernetes deployment with official Docker image

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm trying to run only the Elastic agent as a deployment in a Kubernetes cluster.  The reason I'm doing this is maybe an atypical usage of the Elastic agent: I only want to deploy the HTTP log endpoint integration and have other pods send logs to this Elastic agent.  I'm *not* using it to collect cluster metrics (so the [manifest](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/master/running-on-kubernetes-managed-by-fleet.html) they supply is not relevant to me).

I'm using the image `docker.elastic.co/beats/elastic-agent:8.4.2`.  Apparently, this image needs to write files and directories to `/usr/share/elastic-agent/`, which at first was leading to errors along the lines of `failed: mkdir /usr/share/elastic-agent/state: read-only file system`.  So, I created an `emptyDir` volume and mounted it at `/usr/share/elastic-agent`.  Now, that error disappears, but is replaced with a new error:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: line 14: exec: elastic-agent: not found
```

The entrypoint of the image is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini" "--" "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint"]
```

and it is apparently unable to find `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint`.

A couple questions:

1. Why is it not finding the `elastic-agent` executable?  It is definitely at that path.
2. More broadly: I am new to Elasticsearch -- this is only to set up a QA environment meant to test a product feature where we forward data from certain of our services to customers' Elastic Cloud deployments. I thought deploying the agent as a service in the same cluster where these services run would be the least painful way to do this. Is this not a good way to achieve what I describe in the first paragraph?
3. Assuming I can get the deployment to actually work, is this the way the next steps would go?

   - Create the "Custom HTTP Endpoint Logs" integration on the agent policy, listening on a given port and on all interfaces.
   - Map that port to an external port for the pod.
   - Send data to the pod at that external port.

Comment: That error can come from trying to run a binary for an OS or architecture it wasn't intended for eg ARM binary on x86-64 system.

Comment: @jordanm Good point.  The image I'm using says it's for both arm64/amd64 (https://www.docker.elastic.co/r/beats/elastic-agent) but just to be sure, I changed the tag to amd64 (the architecture shared by the cluster nodes) and I see the same error.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?if yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution and accept it

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that mounting the `emptyDir` volume to `/usr/share` overwrites the elastic-agent binary.  Remove this volume and set `readOnlyRootFilesystem: false`.